# Reducing execution time in python for nested loops

Tags: python, numpy, nested-loops

I have written the following simple code for a numerical simulation. My programming level is beginner.

```
import numpy as np
import time as t
start = t.time()
r=10**-8
alpha=60*(np.pi/180)
gamma_sa=58.6*10**-3 
gamma_sw=25*10**-3
gamma_pa=153*10**-3
gamma_pw=110*10**-3
gamma_aw=72.5*10**-3    
kt= 1.38*10**-23*293 
i=0
##############variables########################
omega=0 
zeta= (3/2 )*np.pi*r**3 *10**-3
dt=0.01 
std=np.sqrt(2*kt*zeta*dt)
for k in range(1,2):
    beta_i=[]
    j_i=[]
    B=[]
    time=np.arange(dt,10,dt)
    Fs_i=[]
    dE_i=[]
    j=0
    for i in range (len(time)):
        j_i.append(j)
        beta=(90-j)
        beta1=(90-j)*(np.pi/180)
        Fs=0
        Ft = (np.random.randn()*std*np.sqrt(dt))/zeta
        beta_i.append(beta)
        del(beta)
        j=(j+Ft+Fs)%360
    MSD=[]
    diff_i=[]
    tau_i=[]
    for l in range(1,len(time)):
        tau=l*dt
        tau_i.append(tau)
        del(tau)
        for i in range(1,(len(time)-l)):
            diff=(j_i[l+i]-j_i[i])**2*dt
            diff_i.append(diff)
        MSD_j=np.sum(diff_i)/np.max(time)
        MSD.append(MSD_j)
        del(MSD_j) 
    np.savetxt("MSD_no_fs%d"%k, MSD)
    np.savetxt("Tau_no_fs%d"%k,tau_i)
print(t.time() - start)
```

The code run successfully and the execution time is ~38s. But if I increase dt from.01 to .001 it seems taking unlimited time as the script keeps running without an error. Can someone explain the execution time dependency with respect to dt, range of k and range of time along with any efficient way to do that? Because I would like to go for dt=.0001, krange (0,100,dt) and time (dt,100,dt). What could be the best practice for this?

PS:  8 gb ram and 3.31 GHz v6 processor.

Comment: Execution time seems to be quadratic in the length of your `time` array because of the two `for` loops. So if you multiply the length by 10 (what you are effectivly doing, when decreasing the step size by factor 10), then execution time will increase by factor 100, so 3800s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The length of `time` is inversely proportionate to the magnitude of `dt`. And you have a nested loop based on the length of `time` in each case. As long as that loop is your hottest code, your code will experience quadratic growth (`O(n**2)`). Stepping from `0.01` to `10` by `0.01` means a length of (close enough) 100 elements, and ~10,000 units of inner loop work. Doing the same thing from `0.001` to `10` by `0.001` means ~1000 elements, and ~1,000,000 units of work, an increase of 100x.

From a starting point of 38 seconds, that's pretty extreme; even if memory weren't an issue, you'd be looking at 3800 seconds (over an hour). And memory *is* an issue; your inner loop repeatedly `append`s to `diff_i`, so you're going from storing ~10,000 `float`s (which on CPython x64 builds seem to occupy 24 bytes a piece, plus 8 bytes for the reference in the `list`), which means you eat about a third of a MB of RAM. With `dt` of `0.001`, that ends up closer to 32 MB, and going to `0.0001` would bring you up to 3.2 GB. Even if you have that much RAM, it means you're no longer benefiting from CPU caches for a lot of stuff, which will likely slow you even more than the straight CPU costs would indicate.

Your code takes *very* little advantage of `numpy`'s features, and could likely be tightened up quite a bit. Doing so would save a great deal of memory, and allow most of the work to be pushed to single function calls with the loops performed in C, running *much* faster than the Python interpreter.

For the simplest improvement, take `diff_i`. Before the loop even runs, you know exactly how many elements it will have, and the calculation could be simplified to simple array operations, converting `j_i` to a `numpy` array before the outer loop even begins, and replacing the loop with a simple series of computations on `j_i` that directly produce `diff_i` as a `numpy` array with no Python level loops at all.

I haven't tested this (no `numpy` on this machine), but a rough stab at this would be to convert `j_i` immediately after it's been populated with:

```
j_i = np.array(j_i)
```

and declare `diff_i` as:

```
diff_i = np.array()
```

then replace:

```
for i in range(1,(len(time)-l)):
    diff=(j_i[l+i]-j_i[i])**2*dt
    diff_i.append(diff)
```

with:

```
new_diff = (j_i[l+1:] - j_i[:-(l+1)]) ** 2 * dt
diff_i = np.concatenate((diff_i, new_diff))
```

Comment: your explanation is really clear and simple. I have sorted out my problem now. I am accepting your answer as it gives me exact answer for the dependencies of execution time. can you please vote my question as I cannot ask many question due to reputation. Thanks.